# Creating a horizontal cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf

a newbie here.
For my thesis I needed to replicate this graph:

[image: Horizontal cylinder alongside the x-axis]

I think it needs to be done in TikZ. It would be extremely helpful if I get an ipnut from the experts here. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={d=4;b=0.5;a=2;},
    x radius=0.5,y radius=2,>=stealth]
 \draw[dashed] (0,0) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=90] 
 (0,-b) node[below]{$x$} -- (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius})
 (d,-b) node[below]{$x+\mathrm{d}x$} -- (d,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}); 
 \draw[thick,->] (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}) -- ++ (a,0) node[above]{$\vec\jmath(x,t)$};
 \draw (d,0) -- (0,0) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-270] -- ++ (d,0);
 \draw[fill,fill opacity=0.4] (d,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}) circle; 
 \draw[thick,->] (d,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}) -- ++ (a,0) node[above]{$\vec\jmath(x+\mathrm{d}x,t)$};
 \draw[->] (-1,-b) -- ++ (d+2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Thank you!